# Using the Themes in the Repository (14.04)

Tags: gnome, themes, 14.04, gtk-2

Ubuntu's unity-tweak-tool only has three themes, Ambiance, Highcontrast, and Radiance.

The repository appears to have quiet a few.  I installed gnome-themes-ubuntu via Synaptic.  The description shows it contains, Dust, Dust San and New Wave.

None of those three appears in the unit-tweak-tool menu.  However they do appear in the gnome-tweak-tool's menu.  When I select them from gnome-tweak-tool, nothing happens.

Is there another step to use these themes in Ubuntu 14.04?

Also, is there some way of getting a list of themes (more than just the default three mentioned above) for Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Those themes are only for gtk2/gnome2. You can download themes from gnome-look.org

Comment: Thanks.  I feel I might be getting somewhere, but I'm having the same bad luck with gnome-look.org.  I downloaded http://gnome-look.org/content/download.php?content=157024&id=1&tan=15182325 from there.  When I put the package in /usr/share/themes it shows up in "gnome-tweak-tool" but not in "unity-tweak-tool".  There's still only three that I can change to, Ambiance, Radiance and Highcontrast.  I'm probably doing something wrong, any ideas?

Comment: Unity 7 no longer uses metacity decorators. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Theming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xangua has answered my question.  From his comments it appears that the Themes in the Ubuntu Repository isn't supported in the current 14.04 version of Ubuntu.  Hopefully the developers will consider putting supported themes there so that the users can have a variety.

There might be other resources, but the only one that I found (so far) is the one linked by Xangua in the comments above.  It might not be the most definitive, but it appears that the all the Themes in the gtk3 category are supported.

If this theory is correct, then anyone having problems with Ubuntu 14.04 and Themes can verify they are using a gtk3 type theme and it should work.

My next question (of which I'll spend time researching first) is to learn how to edit the title bar and borders of the gtk3 themes.

That's my only problem with the stock Ubuntu, is that you can't easily distinguish between the active and inactive windows and it's hard to tell (without window borders) where one window ends and the next begins, especially when having more than one terminal window on your screen.

The Themes in the Repository question is solved!

Comment: Have you figured out how to better distinguish between active and inactive windows? I'm on that same quest.

Comment: Odd -- in my case, nothing ever worked with the `unity-tweak-tool`, but I had great success with `gnome-tweak-tool` .  Maybe I need to be more careful with my 14.04.1 installation.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft All the `unity-tweak-tool` options works on all my 14.04 installations.  There was a time when I used to disable some of the Unity configurations using cli options (such as Global Menu) and try to have gnome fallback for things I was used to... but that was previous versions.  My 14.04 installations are native.  On my systems I wasn't having luck with `gnome-tweak-tool`.  Because of that I eventually removed it.  Try the `unity-tweak-tool` options on a native 14.X install (on a test machine or VM).  See if it works then.

Comment: @GaryBishop Yes.  Look at http://askubuntu.com/a/463060/29012.