# Changing window title color on Utopic

Tags: themes, customization

I'm using 14.10 Utopic Unicorn since today, and I can't find a way to change the title bar color (the bar containing the app's name) and the top bar, both are gray-black by default, it's - in my opinion - very sad and ugly.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Its really easy to do that !
Just right click on the desktop and select `change background image` from the menu.
Then a window will open up.There you will see a simple option to change themes. The name of your current theme is Radiance, Change it to Ambience to get a whitish bright new theme for your title bars.
If you want to customize it more than this, Then you might need [Unity Tweak](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/02/introducing-unity-tweak-tool)
You can understand everything on how to customize ubuntu anyway you want in this link : [Click here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/02/introducing-unity-tweak-tool)
To install Unity Tweak software, Then just follow these simple steps:
**Type/paste this code in Terminal(Ctrl+Alt+T)**

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

That's all !
Its easy  !

Comment: I get a "http://ppa.launchpad.net/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found" on Utopic ... Plus the theme you advised me is white, i'd like it blue ! (yeah i'm complicated .. :p )

Comment: This may be helpful I think ! 
@Rogue 
[Click here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/455677/how-to-edit-the-color-of-the-title-bar-and-border-width-of-a-gtk3-theme#answers-header)

Comment: you don't need the ppa for utopic. just install unity-tweak tool

Answer (score 0):

change by using the theme configuration application (gtk-theme-config) under the Settings Manager; simply turn Custom Highlight Colors "Off" and click "Apply". Of course, if you wish, you can change the highlight color to something you like better than the default.

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UtopicUnicorn/ReleaseNotes/Xubuntu

You can also use a custom theme. There are many of them at 
http://gnome-look.org/ as well as http://compiz-themes.org/ to name a couple.

Perhaps you can find one that appeals to you. Themes can be changed via Appearance in system settings.

[image: Appearance]
You could also use tweak tool or Unity Tweak tool. Available in the Software center.

[image: TweakTools]

If you want to create your own or customize an existing theme, see [How can I create my own ubuntu theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59897/how-can-i-create-my-own-ubuntu-theme)

Comment: I'm not on Xubuntu, i use "regular" ubuntu with Gnome. Is that a problem ?

Comment: I wouldn't expect so. Try it and let us know the result?

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/utopic/i386/gtk-theme-config

Comment: I trird this, here's waht i get (by setting all colors to red) : http://i.imgur.com/8AyvEi5.png
I put a white dot on the area i want to change, it seems like i can't get it to another color through the soft you linked. 
Thanks for reading !

Comment: @Rogue - expanded answer.