# Change icon size Nautilus sidebar Ubuntu 19.04 Yaru Theme

Tags: unity, gnome, nautilus, icons

I am trying to increase icon size of Nautilus sidebar, looks very tiny. I tried tweaking gtk.css file following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030808/what-files-to-edit-to-change-title-bar-and-border-width-of-ubuntu-18-04-lts/1040536#1040536) I can change font size, color etc, `icon-size:` doesn't seems to be working. 
I found [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=549360) at [ubuntuforums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=549360), which does what i am looking for but it's for old version of nautilus and it's deprecated.

After some research I found that I need to  make changes to `~/nautilus-3.32.0/src/nautilus-icon-info.h` source files and build it with all the dependencies installed. but the question is what to change?

I have customized almost everything possible in UI with Ubuntu 19.04 installed on my Dell 5480 Laptop, I have fixed many things but this seems advanced at least for me. Thank you in advance.  [Current Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oD8hM.png)

```
#pragma once

#include <glib-object.h>
#include <gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h>
#include <gdk/gdk.h>
#include <gio/gio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

G_BEGIN_DECLS

#define NAUTILUS_LIST_ZOOM_LEVEL_N_ENTRIES (NAUTILUS_LIST_ZOOM_LEVEL_LARGER + 1)
#define NAUTILUS_CANVAS_ZOOM_LEVEL_N_ENTRIES (NAUTILUS_CANVAS_ZOOM_LEVEL_LARGEST + 1)

/* Maximum size of an icon that the icon factory will ever produce */
#define NAUTILUS_ICON_MAXIMUM_SIZE     320

#define NAUTILUS_TYPE_ICON_INFO (nautilus_icon_info_get_type ())
G_DECLARE_FINAL_TYPE (NautilusIconInfo, nautilus_icon_info, NAUTILUS, ICON_INFO, GObject)

NautilusIconInfo *    nautilus_icon_info_new_for_pixbuf               (GdkPixbuf         *pixbuf,
                                       int                scale);
NautilusIconInfo *    nautilus_icon_info_lookup                       (GIcon             *icon,
                                       int                size,
                                       int                scale);
NautilusIconInfo *    nautilus_icon_info_lookup_from_name             (const char        *name,
                                       int                size,
                                       int                scale);
NautilusIconInfo *    nautilus_icon_info_lookup_from_path             (const char        *path,
                                       int                size,
                                       int                scale);
gboolean              nautilus_icon_info_is_fallback                  (NautilusIconInfo  *icon);
GdkPixbuf *           nautilus_icon_info_get_pixbuf                   (NautilusIconInfo  *icon);
GdkPixbuf *           nautilus_icon_info_get_pixbuf_nodefault         (NautilusIconInfo  *icon);
GdkPixbuf *           nautilus_icon_info_get_pixbuf_nodefault_at_size (NautilusIconInfo  *icon,
                                       gsize              forced_size);
GdkPixbuf *           nautilus_icon_info_get_pixbuf_at_size           (NautilusIconInfo  *icon,
                                       gsize              forced_size);
const char *          nautilus_icon_info_get_used_name                (NautilusIconInfo  *icon);

void                  nautilus_icon_info_clear_caches                 (void);

gint  nautilus_get_icon_size_for_stock_size          (GtkIconSize        size);

G_END_DECLS'
```