# How can i Change LibreOffice UI?

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice, gui, customization

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 , and i am unable to apply personas to my Libreoffice. I also feel that LibreOffice Ui lacks user-friendliness. Is there anyway i can get modded UI for LibreOffice? Or if not is there anyway i can put label/text on icons, so to make it simpler that icon in toolbars can be identified easily ? Anything to improve libreoffice Ui will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using a simple custom toolbar produces a more modern/minimalist feel (without any loss of functionality, since the less-common features are still in the menu):

[image: LO minimal toolbars]

To create a custom toolbar:

- Disable all of the default toolbars from View > Toolbars
- Go to Tools > Customize > Toolbars and create a new toolbar with only the commands that you personally use.
- With your new toolbar selected in the customize window, click the "Toolbar" button iand change "Icons Only" to "Icons and Text".
- Finally, right-click the drag handle on your new toolbar and "Lock Toolbar Position".

Comment: `With your new toolbar selected in the customize window, click the "Toolbar" button iand change "Icons Only" to "Icons and Text".`:) +1 That helped but still i think missing, user-friendliness. Is there any night mode in Libreoffice ? LibreOffice is not that eye pleasing, i guess. :(

Comment: If you use a dark system theme, LO will pick up on that: http://i.stack.imgur.com/83bJ9.png

Comment: Wow dark theme looks better. How can i enable dark theme in LO ? I'm using Mbuntu package on Ubuntu 14.04 unity

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/454372/dark-gtk-theme-for-ubuntu-14-04