# Polar night theme alternative

Tags: themes

Does anyone know a polar night theme alternative without the bluish hightlight? I like the closing icons very much, but the blue is a killer for night work.

Link: http://www.noobslab.com/2014/08/polar-night-dark-gtk-theme-for-ubuntu.html

[image]

Comment: Link to the theme?

Comment: Links to [what you are on about](https://github.com/baurigae/polar-night) help :)

Comment: it can probably can be easily changed...

Answer (score 4):

There are a few alternatives to the [polar night theme](https://github.com/baurigae/polar-night):

- [Noobslab - Ambiance Dark Red](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/05/ambiance-dark-with-red-flavor-gtk-theme.html) - red can be a good choice for a night theme, though generally with computers background lighting is a great idea.
- [Arc Dark](https://github.com/horst3180/Arc-theme) - blue but cool.
- [Delorean Dark](http://www.noobslab.com/2015/06/delorean-dark-theme-now-available-for.html) - still mainly blue though ([gnome-look](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/DeLorean-Dark-Themes?content=159296))
- [Sable Themes Suite](http://www.noobslab.com/2015/06/do-you-like-dark-themes-if-yes-then-use.html) - available in range of colors - also on [DeviantArt](http://killhellokitty.deviantart.com/art/Sable-3-14-31-03222015-507996540).

Alternatively, you could also replace the theme colors *(warning: can be lengthy and boring process)*. These are defined by hex strings such as `#8EC3EB`. So you can search

To do this a while ago I created a rough script to find them in files - it can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/wilfm/6f9b78a0db3553141757#file-grephexcolourcode) and can be used like this:

```
find /home/wilf/Downloads/polar-night-master/ -type f -exec /path/to/scriptfolder/grephexcolourcode {} \; | sort -u
```

Where `/home/wilf/Downloads/polar-night-master/` is where the theme files are located, and `/path/to/scriptfolder/grephexcolourcode` is where the script is located (or just `grephexcolourcode` if it is in the `$PATH`).

You can then replace the colours using `sed` or similar - e.g:

```
sed -i 's/#8EC3EB/#EB8E8E/g' /path/to/theme/file
```

Or using find and replace in a program such as Gedit, BLuefish etc

---

An alternative is to use a normal dark theme (usually blueish - I use Arc-Darker), and then on top of that at night use something like [redshift-gtk](http://jonls.dk/redshift/) to make it more bearable at night. You can launch it with a command similar too:

```
redshift-gtk -l 55.7:12.6 -t 5700:3600 -g 0.8 -m randr -v
```

It will automatically change to be more red at night. This covers the entire screen, so works too with light areas themes can't effect easily (e.g. most webpages, documents etc) but due to blue light being filtered blue things will turn dark so not ideal for graphics work or some themes.

Comment: I hope someone creates a red or orange version of polar night.

Comment: @empedokles - I guess you are searching for the wrong thing - 'polar' is probably referring to ice blue colour, but differently named themes are available - e.g. the ones [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/454372/dark-gtk-theme-for-ubuntu-14-04), as well as loads available on [gnome-look](http://gnome-look.org/index.php?xcontentmode=167) ([example](http://gnome-look.org/index.php?xcontentmode=167)), the [noobslab PPA](https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/themes), [DeviantArt](http://www.deviantart.com/browse/all/?section=&global=1&q=dark+gtk+theme) and elsewhere...

Comment: What I particularily like on that theme are the way they designed the minimizing/closing window icons.

Comment: Depending on your desktop *(it can be done with Gnome 3's Tweak tool, not sure about Unity's)* you can use that theme's window button metacity theme along with another's themes GTK theme - or just copy the pictures out of the [metacity-1](https://github.com/baurigae/polar-night/tree/master/metacity-1) folder over another's themes - this may require editing the relevant metacity xml file....