# Dark GTK theme for Ubuntu 16.04 (Unity)

Tags: 16.04, themes

I have tried to apply dark themes from Ubuntu 14.04 on 16.04 and they do not come out entirely as expected (different colours and such). What native dark themes for Ubuntu 16.04 are out there? I would prefer a theme retaining the default Unity decorations and icons and simply tweaking colours, but other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You could try the Arc Darker or Arc Dark theme. See https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme for more information.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

[**Arc Theme Dark**](https://github.com/horst3180/Arc-theme)

This seems to be a popular theme, albeit somewhat different from the original Unity. This theme also prefers cold colours producing an overall calming and comfortable desktop.

**Update**: After using this theme for a couple of weeks I must say this is the best I ever had with Unity. The choice and combination of colours is spot on, a serene and beautiful theme. Highly recommended.

[image]

This theme can be installed from the Nooblabs PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install arc-theme
```

There is also an Arc icons theme, check more details at the [NoobsLab webpage](http://www.noobslab.com/2016/06/arc-theme-light-dark-versions-and-icons.html).

[**Adapta Dark**](https://github.com/tista500/Adapta)

This theme introduces a number of modifications to window decorations and icons, but the end result is quite crisp. All the colours seem to have been well worked out, producing a nice desktop in different monitors.

[image]

Installation:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:tista/adapta -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install adapta-gtk-theme
```

It might require some tweaking to get activated, check the details [here](http://lmelinux.net/2016/04/25/apply-adapta-dark-theme-ubuntu-unity/) or follow the steps below.

Install `unity-tweak-tool` to apply the newly installed theme using:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Now navigate to `unity-tweak-tool > Appearance > Theme` to choose theme.

Comment: Blue is not a good color at night, even with redshift. Can you alter it?

Comment: All about creating themes in this thread: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47643/how-do-i-make-a-theme-from-scratch-for-unity

Comment: I needed to install `unity-tweak-tool` to enable arc theme, too.

Answer (score 8):

You can also try the Vivacious-zbackout theme.

[image]

Doesn't look great with Firefox. I'm trying to set different themes for GTK and Window theme to see if that helps, not working so far.

Details here: http://www.noobslab.com/2016/04/vivacious-colors-another-great-icon.html

Install commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ravefinity-project/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vivacious-colors
sudo apt-get install vivacious-folder-colors-addon
sudo apt-get install vivacious-colors-gtk-dark
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could complement this answer with install instructions.

Comment: I think (sorry, I'm not 100% sure) it was this:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ravefinity-project/ppa
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install vivacious-colors

Comment: the last command might be >
sudo apt-get install vivacious-colors-gtk-dark

Comment: Do these work for Ubuntu Gnome too?

Comment: Yep, Cinnamon, Mate and Lxde as well

Comment: Can you please Update the answer as  how to install all these themes?

Comment: @MKJ I haven't because I don't know that these instructions actually work. Have you tested them?

Comment: @LuísdeSousa added install instructions. Doing a fresh install and checked that these instructions work.