# Lubuntu window border themes missing

Tags: lubuntu, themes, lxde

I recently installed Lubuntu and I really like it! I got some themes for it but some of them don't work. For example the Zorin themes are shown in the widget ta but not the window border tab. Same thing with the Unity 8 theme and the Ant Nebula theme. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How can I change the gtk theme in Lubuntu to one of these themes that's not visible in the preferences?

Comment: You could try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/454263/how-to-set-borders-around-windows-in-14-04/719851#719851

Comment: The problem for me is that the themes aren't showing up in the appearance settings.

Comment: You need to see if your added themes have an `openbox` subfolder in them. The `openbox` folder should have a `themerc` file. If you don't have the folder I mentioned, it means the theme you're looking at don't support openbox and hence won't be listed re. window borders.

Comment: And window borders aren't related to gtk themes.

Comment: Oh. That might be why then! Can I add the file to the theme?