# Adding a border to gnome-terminal

Tags: themes, gnome-terminal

On a new 14.04 plain vanilla Ubuntu install, with the default theme, nothing special.
Bring up a gnome-terminal window (Ctrl + Alt + t)
The terminal window has no border (nor does it have a resize handle btw) it's a black rectangle.

How can I add a 1px white border (which I find useful when dealing with multiple overlapping gnome-terminal windows)?

Comment: I just switched to Ubuntu 14.04 and the absence of borders around the terminal window annoys me a lot.

Comment: Isnt this a duplicate of this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/448204/how-do-i-add-a-border-around-windows-but-keep-the-current-theme

Comment: Yep it is, but note that I edited gnome-terminal.css instead of unity.css and only the terminal windows have the border.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copy your favorite theme from `/usr/share/theme` to `~/.theme`. Name the theme folder something different from what it was named in the `/usr/share/theme`. This way when you select your chosen them you'll find it by the name you called the folder.

Example:

```
cp -R /usr/share/themes/Radiance/ ~/.themes/MyRadiance
```

Edit the gtk-3 folder of that new directory to make your borders any way you want them. You can also customize other components of the theme. It can be done by editing the UnityDecoration features of the unity.css file located in the apps folder:

```
~/.themes/MyRadiance/gtk-3.0/apps/unity.css
```

To change the borders change the 0's to a different number of the parameter:

```
-UnityDecoration-extents: 28px 0 0 0;
```

You can see all the possible editings [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Theming). Also, to use the new theme you have to install the Unity Tweak Tool.

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

To apply this for terminal add the following to `gnome-terminal.css`: `UnityDecoration { -UnityDecoration-extents: 28px 1px 1px 1px; }`

Comment: Will this allow me to add borders only on gnome-terminal windows? I would prefer to limit the effect of my fiddling to only what is needed.

Comment: As shown in the directory path, it applies to gtk. You can surely give a try.

Comment: I followed these instructions and instead of modifying unity.css, I added the following to gnome-terminal.css:

UnityDecoration {
    -UnityDecoration-extents: 28px 1px 1px 1px;
}

Comment: @gb. I think what you need is explained by frankie now. Cheers

Comment: @AnanduMDas Better to [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/525000/edit) your question and add frankie's [comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/481010/adding-a-border-to-gnome-terminal#comment716211_525000) also.

Comment: @AnanduMDas I think the default theme I got is Ambiance, not Radiance, so I applied your patch to a MyAmbiance instead. Moreover, it seems that this patch to gnome-terminal.css applies a thin border to all applications. You could also explain a bit how to use unity-tweak-tool. But still, this works, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can come close to the effect you're looking for if you use compizconfig-settings-manager.

Navigate to the 'Unity' plugin and select 'Decorations'. Check the box 'Override Theme Settings' and you can give windows a 'window shadow radius' and a color and opacity.  But, you can also set X and Y shadow offsets.  Set those offsets to 0, set the shadows to white or whatever you want for active/inactive windows, turn the opacity up, and then you'll have borders (should be close enough anyway).

Hopefully it's good enough to get on with, best of luck!

Comment: Thanks, I tried it. It is kind of hackish, and it will apply on all applications, while I need a "normal" border on my terminal (the same that I get when opening multiple tabs).

Comment: Apparently you can get what you're looking for by customizing your theme CSS locally in ~/.themes, or by downgrading the package 'light-themes' to the one that came with 13.xx -- both options are detailed in [this post on getting back window borders](http://askubuntu.com/questions/454263/how-to-set-borders-around-windows).