# Nautilus doesnt have window border on Gnome shell

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, window

I have a problem with Nautilus that Nautilus window border is disappearing.

[image: Nautilus with no window border]

As you can see, there's no window border. What can i do to get it back ?

Using: Nautilus 3.10.1
      and Gnome Shell 3.10.4

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a border around windows but keep the current theme?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/448204/how-do-i-add-a-border-around-windows-but-keep-the-current-theme) also this one http://askubuntu.com/questions/454263/how-to-set-borders-around-windows-in-14-04

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to popular belief, this isn't the way gnome shell apps are supposed to look.

From the [webupd8 blog](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/08/how-to-disable-gtk3-client-side.html):

Starting with GNOME 3.10, some GNOME applications have switched to "header bars" or "client-side decorations". These CSD (client-side decorations) don't work properly in some desktop environments / shells - for instance, in Ubuntu 14.04, Unity doesn't support CSD and because of this, some applications look broken.

Ubuntu 14.04 or 14.10 users can install gtk3-nocsd by using the main WebUpd8 PPA. To add the PPA and install gtk3-nocsd, use the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gtk3-nocsd
```

Here's an example: to disable the client-side decorations for gThumb 3.3.2, open its desktop file as root with a text editor (I'll use Gedit below):

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/applications/gthumb.desktop
```

And in this file, search for the line that starts with "Exec=" and right after "=" and before "gthumb", add the following (without removing anything!):

```
env LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/gtk3-nocsd/gtk3-nocsd.so
```

After editing gthumb.desktop, the "Exec=" line should look like this:

```
Exec=env LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/gtk3-nocsd/gtk3-nocsd.so gthumb %U
```

See the [source](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/08/how-to-disable-gtk3-client-side.html) for more information and examples and download sources.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to hack apart every desktop file shortcut just to show title bars. I gave up and just installed Nemo. It is very similar to nautilus and doesn't have the same problem.

Add the PPA and install the latest Nemo with Unity tweaks/fixes by using the commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/nemo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nemo nemo-fileroller
```

Read the [source](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html) post for optional extensions and more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

that is just the way the new gnome shell looks.

You may want to look at some other desktop environments.

here are some Official Ubuntu derivatives with the same base just different looks.

http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/derivatives

if you want something like the old gnome2 style you may want to see about trying Linux Mint

http://www.linuxmint.com/

its a distribution based on Ubuntu but the desktop environment was forked from the old gnome2 when the gnome development team went to the new style like you have now.

Comment: Yea i know it, but i just want to get window border back

Comment: I'll update my answer with some other options

Comment: can i get nautilus window border work on gnome shell ?

Comment: are you using ubuntu gnome or did you install gnome shell in a normal ubuntu installation?

Comment: iam install gnome shell with `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`. Install gnome shell on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: look for the gnome-tweak-tool in the software center. It might have what you need.

Comment: @Klyn "*its a distribution based on Ubuntu but the desktop environment was forked from the old gnome2*" If you're talking about the MATE desktop environment, [that is also available for Ubuntu](http://wiki.mate-desktop.org/download#ubuntu) -- see also [How do I install MATE (the desktop environment)?](http://askubuntu.com/q/87040/22949) and [the new Ubuntu MATE project, starting with 14.10](https://ubuntu-mate.org/). (Btw, MATE is actually not the default desktop environment in Linux Mint--the default is instead [Cinnamon](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/)).

Comment: No, gnome shell does not look this way. Just launch any other app and see for yourself.