# How to get a REAL global dark theme in Ubuntu Gnome 14.10?

Tags: gnome, 14.10, themes

After years (hours) of looking for an answer, unable to find a working one, I'm going to ask you.

How do I change the color of this (or any other than gnome app) to match the dark theme? I find it highly annoying, and the solution that everybody suggests (gnome shell theme) simply won't work.

[image]

I've enabled custom shell themes, but not a single shell theme that I would even consider using have changed the color of these windows.

This is what my tweak-tool looks like:

[image]

Under window (or any other than shell theme), there's nothing else but adwaita and high contrast.

Comment: Is [this answer of mine](http://askubuntu.com/a/575838/283843) what you are looking for?

Comment: it's still blury to get what you want to change? is it border color or the theme won't apply completely? and how and what is the source that you installing themes from?

Comment: Global dark theme doesn't seem to affect any other apps than gnome. For example, sublime text, filezilla etc, are white, instead of the global dark that should be used.

Comment: I use themes from noobslab website they always work smoothly if you need editing border colors or backgrounds to your specific requirements you gotta edit `.css` files like in **KasiyA** comment. That what I always do when I want some specific color. It requires just a little `c++` skills though, just to understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Download this zip(Numix Flatstudio Dark Theme): https://www.dropbox.com/s/hvq89fo7rojpr5h/Numix-flatsudio-dark.zip?dl=0 (I have made a few changes to this to match my shell theme)
- Open terminal and type this:

  ```
  sudo chown [username] /usr/share/themes && sudo chown [username] /usr/share/icons
  ```

  replacing `[username]` with your username.
- Unzip this downloaded zip into `/usr/share/themes`
- Download this zip(Shell Theme): https://www.dropbox.com/s/d8ynaj6jnsktln4/Ozon.zip?dl=0
- Unzip this downloaded zip into `/usr/share/themes`
- Download this zip(Icon Pack): https://www.dropbox.com/s/850tkeijmraskfk/Ultra-Flat-Orange.zip?dl=0
- Unzip this downloaded zip into `/usr/share/icons`
- Open Tweak tool.  Turn off the **Global Dark Theme**. There will be Numix-flatstudio-dark under the **Window** and the **GTK+** dropdown. Select those. Under the **Shell Theme** dropdown, there will be **Ozon-shell-master**. Select this also. Select **Ultra-Flat-Orange** in the **Icons** dropdown menu.
- Now you will have a global dark theme

[image: Tweak Tool]

[image: File Manager Themed]

Comment: Aww yiss, this is it. It's a bit too bright but I'm fluent with CSS as a front-end developer, so I'll adjust it a bit. Enjoy your rep! ;)

Comment: Thanks! Did you want the icons btw? @Christian

Comment: I could take a look at them, but for some reason they won't appear in the menu. I don't have the time to do it right now though. Also, I changed your command a bit for it to work. (You forgot sudo on the `&& chown` part)

Comment: Yea lol stupid mistake :P Icons will be in the Answer post

Comment: @Christian Icons Done! See the post to find how to get them!

Comment: Ooooh, shiny! Nice icons. Will appreciate.

Comment: Isn't that font Quicksand?

Comment: The dropbox link is broken. How can I achieve this on Ubuntu 18.04?