# How to create colored borders for all windows?

Tags: unity, gnome, themes, gtk3

Is there a simple `gtk.css` tweak (or similar) that allows me to have a colored border on all created GNOME/Unity windows?

Something like this on web page:

```
body {
    border: 10px solid #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes these files are located in (e.g for default Ambiance theme) :

```
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/apps/
```

you can edit **nautilus.css** or **unity.css** as you wish

[How do I add a border around windows but keep the current theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/448204/how-do-i-add-a-border-around-windows-but-keep-the-current-theme)

Good practice is to copy theme you wish to modify to **~/.themes/** and than making changes.
At the end you can use **Unity Tweak Tool** to change to your modified theme.

After copying your Ambiance theme to ~/.themes/Ambiance2, change in:

~/.themes/Ambiance2/gtk-3.0/apps/**unity.css** :

```
  -UnityDecoration-extents: 28px 0 0 0;
```

to

```
  -UnityDecoration-extents: 28px 10 10 10;
```

then:

```
UnityDecoration.bottom {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #ff0080; /* shade (@bg_color, 0.7); */
}

UnityDecoration.left,
UnityDecoration.right {
    background-color: #ff0080; /* shade (@bg_color, 0.7); */
```

Also change in **UnityDecoration.left*** and **UnityDecoration.right*** sections to **background-image: none**;

It will give you pink border. You can change it to what ever you want. Just change this hex **#ff0080** to another.

Comment: Thanks, but still cannot figure out how to do this. Let me try to rephrase what I'm doing. I want to be able to draw very visible borders [like in this picture](http://i1.aijaa.com/b/00882/14097694.jpg)

And btw I'm using 12.04.