# gnome term shows no boundary frame(or bezel?) in left, right and bottom side

Tags: gnome, window-manager

I'm on ubuntu 20.04 and using gnome.
The terminal (the one made with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>) has no edge frame bezel area on the left, right and bottom, so sometimes it's confusing when it's overlapping with another window. I think having some bezel area is better. How can I adjust the bezel area?
please see the image.[image]

ADD : I found in the preference of the terminal window, I can set the theme variant to `Dark`(only 3 variants) and it has a slight border line, but not conspicuous enough for me. I searched the configuration, no option for setting border line width.

Comment: I found this question has the answer. https://askubuntu.com/questions/976030/how-to-enable-add-window-borders-in-17-10-18-04